# Exponents and absolute value w/ complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

A simple stupid question that I should already know the answer to:

Is this true: $\left|z^5\right| = \left|z\right|^5$ where z is a complex number with a non-zero imaginary component.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, it is true for any complex number, just note that $\overline{z^5}=(\overline z)^5$, now use the definition of absolute value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write in complex form

$z = re^{i\theta} \implies |z|^n = r^n|e^{i\theta}|^n = r^n\cdot1 = r^n$

$|z^n| = |r^ne^{in\theta}| = r^n|e^{in\theta}| = r^n\cdot 1 = r^n$

Comment: You assume what you want to prove in the very first line.

Comment: What did I assume?

Comment: $r$ is a real and positive number, and $|e^{i\theta}| = 1$ @Allawonder

Comment: I thought you were trying to show that $|z^n|=|z|^n.$ On the other side of the implication in the first line, you intend $$|z|^n=|re^{i\theta}|^n=(|r||e^{i\theta}|)^n=\cdots.$$ You already assume that this is true for products of real and complex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true.

Note that for any two complex numbers $z$ and $w$, we have

$$|zw|=|z||w|.$$

With $z=w$ we get $|z^2|=|z|^2$, and using induction you get $$|z^n|=|z|^n$$ for any natural number $n$.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from the identity $$|zw|=|z||w|,$$ which may be verified by writing both the involved numbers in either rectangular or polar form, computing both sides separately and noting that they are equal.

By taking $z=w$ and using the identity repeatedly, you have that $|z^n|=|z|^n$ for any positive integer $n.$